# Pygame + RPI-Camera Container

Tags: python, camera

Currently I'm using this code, to display my pygame on 2.8" TFT with Touchscreen while keeping the HDMI-Port as main-output:

```
import pygame, sys, os

os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "fbcon"
os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDRV"] = "TSLIB"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDEV"] = "/dev/input/touchscreen"
```

Is there a way to create a container, something similar to `Rect` in Pygame, that is able to display the pi-camera preview?

When I use:

```
cam = picamera.PiCamera()
cam.resolution = (220,140)
cam.start_preview()
```

My application is still displayed on the TFT, but the Camera-Feed is displayed on the HDMI-Output on-top of bash.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this can't be done. As [the FAQ explains](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.5/faq.html#can-i-put-the-preview-in-a-window) the camera's preview system simply gets the GPU to overlay the camera output on top of the usual video output.

There was a very cool [adafruit camera project](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-wifi-raspberry-pi-touch-cam) that seemingly managed to get a preview working on a PiTFT display (which I assume is the sort of display you're talking about), and which was also using picamera but when I dug into the code they were (very cleverly) "cheating" by taking lots of consecutive unencoded captures and displaying them one after the other.